# How many times fragment shader is executed?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I have an OpenGL code, with 3 different shader programs.
I have a simple question, I know fragment shaders are executed for every every fragment in the scene.
But is there a way using which we can find how many fragments are there in the scene? 
Correct me if i am wrong, but the fragment shader is executed for each fragments, so

Number of fragments = number of times fragment shader executed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the number of fragments which passed the depth test](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/getting-the-number-of-fragments-which-passed-the-depth-test)

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question let's look at how the typical OpenGL pipline works.

Vertex Shader -> Geometry Shader (Optional) -> Clipping -> Rasterization -> Pixel Shader ---------------> Fragments Merge.

I want to stress the fact that one pixel is not necessarily one [fragment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8977/what-is-a-fragment/8981#8981), multiple fragment can be combined to make one pixel, other fragments are discarded due to depth test , stencil test, blending. A Fragment shader will be executed for those fragments even though they might merged/discarded later.

I don't know a way give you exact number of the fragments in a scene, maybe there is a tool for NVidia or ATI than can give you how many times a fragment shader is executed.

Regardless of the actual numbers it's important to understand that due to the parallel nature of the GPU fragment shaders are executed on parallel on multiple fragments, it is also more important to profile your application and understand if it is GPU bound and if the bottleneck is in the vertex or fragment stage. here is a good article from GPU gems that [explains how the GPU works](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter30.html).

Comment: One fragment != pixel.
And multiple fragments can be combined to make one pixel... that is what we call Multi-sampling. :)

Comment: not only multisampling, depth test might result in fragments not shown are still processed by the fragment shader. Also applies for other kind of tests (stencil , alpha test etc)

Comment: It's very important to consider fragments that are overwritten due to ZPass. This is why in certain circumstances, rendering front-to-back can help performance in fill-rate limited applications.

Comment: The amount of work done for each fragment is also an important factor; a z-only pre-pass is most definitely not comparable to a complex lighting setup.  This honestly seems a meaningless metric and I'd question if there's much value in having it.

Answer (score 5):

You can, with a suitably recent version of GL, use the query objects support.  See [glGenQueries](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenQueries.xml) and [glBeginQuery](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBeginQuery.xml) for documentation on their use.

With this, you can use `GL_SAMPLES_PASSED` as the query type.  Assuming you aren't doing anything to disable early-Z, this should get you close to what you're looking for, enough for performance measurements at the least.

Answer (score 2):

A fragment shader is executed for each fragment once.One fragment is one pixel. so it depends on what are you rendering:

For example if it takes up the whole screen( like a post-process effect ) it is executed as many times as many pixels are there on your screen.( Resolution.x * Resolution.y ).

So basically it is called once for each pixel.

If you are interested for more exact numbers, you could use shader atomics to test specific cases.

Here are some links about the usage of shader atomic counters. They are basically counters that are consistent across shaders, their usage is more performance expensive tough.

[link1](http://www.geeks3d.com/20120309/opengl-4-2-atomic-counter-demo-rendering-order-of-fragments/),
[link2](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/opengl-short-tutorials/opengl-atomic-counters/)

Comment: If you're using multisampling (MSAA, etc.) it's number of pixels * number of samples.

Comment: @akltar, would you like to elaborate more on shader automics?
I googled it, didnt find anything.

Comment: @RobertRouhani No, with MSAA the fragment shader is still executed once per pixel per primitive, not for each sample.  (Unless you specifically turn on sample-frequency shading, which is not usual.)

Comment: @NathanReed Oh, right, that's SSAA/FSAA, MSAA just checks coverage at the sub-pixel level... my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use openGL atomic counter to increment a value inside your fragment shader. Here is a tutorial on opengl atomics: [OpenGL Atomic Counters](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/opengl-short-tutorials/opengl-atomic-counters/)